# Angular Dart - retrieve param from parent route

Tags: angular, dart

In a template I have the following routerLink:
`[routerLink]="['../myObjects', {'id': object.id}, 'mySubObjectsList']"`

The routing is ok, but I cannot get the parameter value `id` in my mySubObjectsList component. `_routeParams.params` is empty.

I guess this is because the parameter is set to my parent routing component `myObjects`.

Is there a way to get it in my subcomponent?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy way.
You can add the params to a service in the parent and make that service available to the child:

```
@Service()
class ParentRouteParams {
  Map<String,String> params;
  // using a StreamController is probably a good idea
}

@Component(
  selector: 'parent',
  providers: const [ParentRouteParams],
  ...
)
class Parent {
  Parent(this._parentRouteParams);

  final ParentRouteParams _parentRouteParams;

  @override
  void onActivate(_, RouterState current) {
    _parentRouteParams.params = current.parameters;
  }
}
```

```
@Component(
  selector: 'child'
  ...
)
class Child {
  Parent(this._parentRouteParams);

  final ParentRouteParams _parentRouteParams;

}
```